# Inapppurchase invalid product id - iPhone StoreKit

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

I'm building an iPhone app and having a really hard time testing my support for in-app purchase using StoreKit.
Specifically, I am unable to retrieve a product ID using SKProductRequest, and so I can't get far enough to even try to attempt the purchase.

Here's what I have done so far:
- Created an App in iTunes Connect
- Created an App ID will a valid Bundle ID in the Provisioning Portal, and configured it to Enable In-App Purchase (I see a green ball for this App ID)
- Created a Provisioning Profile using the App ID above for my iPhone 3GS that I use for development (iPhone is updated with the latest current firmware) and imported it into XCode
- Set the Bundle ID for my application in Info.plist to match the Bundle ID (full Bundle ID, like "com.company.myapp")
- Created an In-App purchase associated with my iPhone app above, set its ProductID to "com.company.app.feature", set the type as Consumable and marked it as "Cleared for sale". The current status is "Pending Developer Approval"
- Updated my code to use the ProductID of the in-app purchase created above when requesting Product Information using SKProductRequest
- Signed out of my iTunes Store account on my phone, and enabled In-App Purchases on the device
- Built a Debug build of my app targeted for my phone with the Provisioning Profile above
- Deployed my app on my device using XCode and tried to run the StoreKit code with the USB cable attached.

When I issue a request for the product from the store, the productsRequest:didReceiveResponse: delegate is invoked, but the productID I request shows up as invalid.

Next, I also tried to upload a binary for my app and see if that made a difference, but it didn't. The current status of my binary is "Developer Rejected", if it matters.
It has been well over 24 hours since I created the app/in-app purchase

Thinking that it might have something to do with my device, I reset an iPod touch to factory settings updated with the latest firmware. I created a provisioning profile for the iPod touch and deployed the app to it using XCode. That didn't help either - I see the same "invalidProduct" problem.

Any suggestions of what I should do next?

Comment: have you tried http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/ walkthrough

Answer (score 0):

[Here you have](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/) many possible causes of Invalid Product ID